# Mysql multi join query returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 4.0305 seconds.)

Tags: php, mysql

I have to use to multi join query in php because my tables doesn't have straight relationship.
I have 3 tables thoes are one by one related: office_capacity_stats wiht users and, users with zone. and I need to get data from office_capacity_stats  and zone. but
it doesn't have any result, it has just column name of first table.
my query:

```
select o.* FROM office_capacity_stats o join users u on o.userid_office=u.userid_office join zone z on u.subzone=z.id where z.id=133
```

Comment: Can you please confirm the `office_capacity_stats` table and `users` table contain the same `userid_office`? If you provide table schema then that would be great.

Comment: Please remove images add all details in text format. Add table description, some data examples and expected results. If you have query performance you should post explain plan as well

Comment: @ErgestBasha it just show column name of  office_capacity_stats